# Creating Bayesian Network from Dataframe with Sequence of Steps

Tags: python, classification, prediction, recommendation-engine, bayesian-networks

I am trying to take data that comprises a series of steps and turn it into a bayesian network in order to predict whether a particular person requires intervention at any given step. However, I am not sure how to convert my sequential data into a bayesian network.

My current understanding is that I need to: 1)define nodes (my steps) and 2) specify the conditional probabilities for each node. However, I'm not sure how do I define parents and children or algorithmically create the conditional probabilities for X number of steps which may happen before or after each other for any given person in my data set.

If anyone has any suggested steps to take or starter code to help me go from a dataframe like the one below to a bayesian network, it would be appreciated.

[image]